# awk: keep records with the highest value, comparing those that share other fields

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm trying to write an awk script that keeps the records with a highest value in a given field, but only comparing records that share two other fields.

I'd better give an example -- this is the input.txt:

```
X A 10.00
X A 1.50
X B 0.01
X B 4.00
Y C 1.00
Y C 2.43
```

I want to compare all the records sharing the same value in the 1st and 2nd fields (X A, X B or Y C) and pick the one with a highest numerical value in the 3rd field.

So, I expect this output:

```
X A 10.00
X B 4.00
Y C 2.43
```

With this snippet I am able to pick the record with max value in the 3rd field (but it's not taking into account the previous fields, and it's not outputting them either):

```
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($2>max) max=$2} END {print max}' input.txt
```

Current (unwanted) output:

```
10.00
```

Any ideas? I can use gawk.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '{k=$1 OFS $2} $3>a[k]{a[k]=$3} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
X A 10.00
X B 4.00
Y C 2.43
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you please explain what the "OFS $2" part is doing in the first bracket block?

Comment: There I am storing value of `$1 OFS $2` into variable `k` where default `OFS` (output field separator) is space.

Comment: Nice, thanks!

I've got an additional, related question: what if I want to do the same but just using the 1st field as a key, but outputting the 2nd as well? The output should be:

`X A 10.00`
`Y C 2.43`

i.e., look for the max value in the 3rd field among records sharing the 1st, regardless of the 2nd (or others)

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question since I didn't understand this new scenario.

Comment: In case somebody is interested in the follow-up of my last, off-topic question, I've written this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253200/awk-keep-records-with-the-highest-value-that-share-a-field-while-ignoring-othe/ ; Ideas welcome!