# awk: keep records with the highest value that share a field, while ignoring other fields

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Imagine that you want to keep the records with the highest value in a given field of a table, just comparing within the categories defined by another field (and ignoring the contents of the others).

So, given the input nye.txt:

```
X A 10.00
X A 1.50
X B 0.01
X B 4.00
Y C 1.00
Y C 2.43
```

You'd expect this output:

```
X A 10.00
Y C 2.43
```

This is an offshot of this previous, related thread: [awk: keep records with the highest value, comparing those that share other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29239080/awk-keep-records-with-the-highest-value-comparing-those-that-share-other-field)

I already have a solution (see below), but ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this with **awk**:

```
awk '$3>=a[$1]{a[$1]=$3; b[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a)print b[i]}' File
```

For each `1st column value` (X, Y etc..), if the `3rd column value` is greater than or equal to the previously stored great value (i.e `a[$i]`; initially it will be `0` by default), update a[$i] with this `3rd column value`. Also save the entire line in array b. Within `END` block, print the results.

**Output:**

```
AMD$ awk '$3>a[$1]{a[$1]=$3; b[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a)print b[i]}' File
X A 10.00
Y C 2.43
```

Comment: That seems like the natural way. Since the question is tagged "gawk", let me leave a [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) that details how to easily control the order of output with GNU awk. Could be relevant.

Comment: Yours is simpler and better, thanks! Mine made use of the "split string" function to keep the unused fields, which is not necessary if you define two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
awk '{ k=$1 } { split(a[k],b," ") } $3>b[2] { a[k]=$2" "$3 } END { for (i in a) print i,a[i] }' nye.txt
```

The first bracket block indicates which field defines the categories within which you want to compare the other field (1st and 3rd fields, in this case).

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29239235/3298298)

Ideas welcome!